# Azure WebJobs and Visual Studio 2017

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, visual-studio-2017

I need to deploy an Azure WebJob and tried to follow [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/websites-dotnet-deploy-webjobs#convertlink). Is this supposed to work in Visual Studio 2017? I have none of the mentioned context menu entries (tried two different machines).

Answer (score 6):

> I have none of the mentioned context menu entries (tried two different machines).

What type of project did you create?  Until now, we could see the [Publish as Azure WebJob…] context menu when we create a Console App(.NET Framework) in Visual Studio 2017.

[image]

You also need to check whether you have checked the Azure Development option when you install your Visual Studio 2017. If you did not do that, you could re-run the Visual Studio 2017 install exe file to update your Visual Studio 2017.

[image]

If your project type is Console App(.NET Core),  the publish function is not available until now.

Comment: Does this mean I can't publish a Console App (.Net Core) as a webjob? Or can I use the normal "Publish" option?

Answer (score 3):

No.

WebJobs deployment features are available in Visual Studio **2015** when you install the Azure SDK for .NET.

It's not yet available in VS2017.

EDIT: See post below.

Comment: It is now...install the azure development workload by following instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/install-visual-studio#step-4---select-workloads)